# How to configure a glue job to extract data from aurora database and load into s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

Can we add aurora database directly as source while defining a glue job? I don't see the option in the drop-down in source on the console. Is it mandate that we will have to use glue data catalogue and the crawlers for the job to run or can we simply define a job with database as source and s3 as target and avoid data catalogue and crawlers?

I am a bit confused on how exactly this works in my scenario. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that populating the Aurora tables to Glue data catalogue (using Glue crawlers) is mandatory for Glue visual editor. The editor requires these metadata (e.g., column names, data type) without actually connecting to the Aurora database.

However, in Glue the script editor and the Jupyter notebook environment can work without data catalogue and crawlers.